# Swift: Decode string to NSData to display image in ImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I updated XCode today. I am using XCode 6.1.1. After updating I get an error with this line.

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: jsonDict["binary"] as NSString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)!)
```

The error message is: Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'.

I would  like to decode a String to NSData to display the image in imageView.
jsonDict is a NSDictionary.
What is wrong here? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `jsonDict["binary"]` returns an `Optional` (it may be nil). You need to unwrap it first:

```
if let str: String = jsonDict["binary"] {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: str, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(0))
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much. It seems that a few things have changed with this update. I am using FireSocket for Websocket connections. It doesnt't work anymore. I have too many errors in FireSocket.swift. Do you know an alternative library for XCode 6.1.1?

Comment: @masterWN No, I don't know about FireSocket... Maybe try asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `!` in `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)!`.
`NSDataBase64DecodingOptions`'s `init(rawValue:)` is non `Optional`.

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
struct NSDataBase64DecodingOptions : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt)
    init(rawValue: UInt)
```

So you don't need `!` here. To be more better, you can use just `nil` here:

```
NSData(base64EncodedString: jsonDict["binary"] as NSString, options: nil)
```